# woocommerce if the order use a specific payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a specific rule if the order uses a specific gateway for a plugin.
They have a public function for orders, is it possible I add some code to the function if the order used mycred gateway as well?

Here is the public function.

````
        /*
         * @param int
         * @return none
         */
        if ($order_id){
            if (is_object($order_id)){
                $order_id = (isset($order_id->ID)) ? $order_id->ID : 0;
            }
            $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type);
        }
    }```
````

Comment: ``` public function make_referral_refuse($order_id=0){
  /*
   * @param int
   * @return none
   */
  if ($order_id){
   if (is_object($order_id)){
    $order_id = (isset($order_id->ID)) ? $order_id->ID : 0;
   }
   $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type);
  }
 }```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/) you can calculate the order payment method via:

```
$order->get_payment_method_title();
```

Therefore, you could check if "Mycred" (or whatever title you gave it) equals that calculation and only then proceed with the function:

```
if ( "Mycred" == $order->get_payment_method_title() ) {
   $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried this code, but it is not working, can you help me to check it?
`code`
 public function make_referral_refuse($order_id=0){
  /*
   * @param int
   * @return none
   */
  if ( "Mycred" == $order->get_payment_method_title() ) {
   $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type);
  }
  if ($order_id){
   if (is_object($order_id)){
    $order_id = (isset($order_id->ID)) ? $order_id->ID : 0;
   }
   $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type);
  }
 }

Comment: `public function make_referral_refuse($order_id=0){
 if ( "Mycred" == $order->get_payment_method_title() ) {
  $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type); 
  }
 if ($order_id){
  if (is_object($order_id)){
   $order_id = (isset($order_id->ID)) ? $order_id->ID : 0;
  }
  $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type);
 }
}`

Comment: seems still not formated, is it ok like this?

Comment: Better. Anyway I don't have the MyCred plugin so I can't give you code that is tested and works - try play with several payment method titles e.g. "My Cred" as I don't know what that could be. Have you customized the title within the Woo settings?

Comment: Thank you very much, let me try more payment titles, do you have any idea for using a filter? I posted it in the other answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function make_referral_refuse($order_id=0){
    /*
    * @param int
    * @return none
    */
    if ( "Mycred" == $order->get_payment_method_title() ) {
        $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type);
        }
    if ($order_id){
        if (is_object($order_id)){
            $order_id = (isset($order_id->ID)) ? $order_id->ID : 0;
        }
        $this->referral_refuse($order_id, $this->source_type);
    }
}
```

I can not format the code with comment, So I posted here.

Btw, I found a filter of the plugin, I am not sure which is the better way,

Those are the filters, I am not sure which one should I use, but I tried both of the 2 filters, when checkout it shows internal error, I think the code may have some error.

```
uap_filter_referral_amount
uap_public_filter_on_referral_insert_amount_value
```

The flowing code is what I have tried and shows internal error when checkout:

```
function exclude_mycred_gateway( $order ){
    $payment_title = $order->get_payment_method_title();
    if ( $payment_title ) {
        $payment_title == "myCRED";
        return "0";
    }
}

add_filter( 'uap_filter_referral_amount', 'exclude_mycred_gateway');
```